# Function to create an Alphabetical Table List with Indexes from an Array

Tags: php, arrays

given an array, is there a way to output a 4 column html table with an alphabetically-sorted list of the array's contents with the first index letter of the alphabet highlighted (only if there is an element in the array that starts with any given letter of the alphabet)?

In other words, say I have the array:

```
$array = ('apple','pear','banana','pomegranate','orange','peach','clementine');
```

I want an output like this:

```
_________________________________________
|A      |C          |P           |O      |
|apple  |clementine |pear        |orange |
|B      |O          |pomegranate |       |
|banana |orange     |peach       |       |
------------------------------------------
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for a ready-made function to generate such an alphabetic list from an array and display such list in a table with index letters, like this:

[image: alphabetic array list in a table]

Since I couldn't find one I wrote one and I am posting here for everyone to use:

```
    function alphaTable($array,$columns=NULL) {
    $i = 0;
    $index_css_style_name = 'alphaindex';
    $entry_css_style_name = 'alphaentry';
    sort($array); // sort our array alphabetically
    $list = array(); // create empty array which will contain the alphabetic index list
    while ( $i < count($array) ) {  // cycle through our array
        $index[$i] = substr($array[$i],0,1); // get first character of entry
        if ( $i == 0 && is_numeric($index[$i]) ) {
            $list[] = '         <div class="'.$index_css_style_name.'">[0-9]</div>'."\n"; // add the default index for numbers/digits
            $list[] = $names[$i][0].'<br />'; // add the regular non-index entries to our alphabetic index list array
        } else if ( $i > 0 && !is_numeric($index[$i]) && $index[$i] != $index[($i - 1)] ) { // if it is not numeric then it's a letter of the alphabet
            $list[] = '         <div class="'.$index_css_style_name.'">'.strtoupper($index[$i]).'</div>'."\n"; // add the uppercase letter of the current index
            $list[] = $names[$i][0].'<br />'; // add the regular non-index entries to our alphabetic index list array
        } else {
            $list[] = $names[$i][0].'<br />'; // add the regular non-index entries to our alphabetic index list array
        }
        $i++;
    }
    unset($i);

    // check if the function calls specifies a numnber of desired columns for the table
    if ( !isset($columns) )
        $columns = 4; // if number of columns is not specified, let's set it to 4
    $epc = count($list) / $columns; // get the entries per columns
    $epc = ceil($epc); // round it up!!

    $i = 1; // let's start at 1 so when we multiply by 0 it doesn't return 0
    $e = 0;
    $table = "\n".'<table border=1>'."\n";
    $table .= ' <tr valign="top">'."\n";
    while ( $i <= $columns ) { // less or equal to (because we started at 1)
        $table .= '     <td>'."\n";
        while ( $e < ($epc * $i) ) { // we increment e within the i while loop so that we can continue with the entries in the table
            if ( !empty($list[$e]) )
                if ( substr_count($list[$e],$index_css_style_name) > 0 )    // to prevent double <span> tags we check whether our desired index css styling is present
                    $table .= $list[$e]; // if it's an index we just add it to the table
                else
                    $table .= '             <span class="'.$entry_css_style_name.'">- '.$list[$e].'</span>'."\n"; // if it's an entry we style it and add it to the table
            $e++;
        }
        $table .= '     </td>'."\n";
        $i++;
    }
    $table .= ' </tr>'."\n";
    $table .= '</table>'."\n";
    unset($i);
    unset($e);
    return $table;
}
```

Just trying to give back to the community that has helped me so much when I was stuck on something.
Feel free to use.
You are welcome ;-)

Comment: `while ( $i < count($array) ) { ` run count once, not on every loop, even better use `foreach()`. there are 2 loops when you only need one.